# Not getting style on text view

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, styles

I have tried adding style to my text. I am getting the style executed on some edit text and not getting executed on some other edit text. Unable to understand what's going wrong. Here is my output

[image]

I can view style on edit text view of  Location details from and not on edit text view of Location details to.

please help..

**Style XML**

```
<style name="AudioFileInfoOverlayText">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/DriversNear"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


                <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    tools:context=".GoRideActivity"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/From"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="08dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:background="@drawable/line2"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_place_black_48dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/Text_from"
                        android:text="@string/Loc"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                        android:layout_marginTop="05dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_description_black_48dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:id="@+id/editText_from_details"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="@string/LocationDetails"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewHouseDetailsFrom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText"
                    android:text="@string/HouseDetails" />

</LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/To"
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="08dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                    android:background="@drawable/line2"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_place_black_48dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="05dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/Text_to"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/Loc"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_description_black_48dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:id="@+id/editText_to_details"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:hint="@string/LocationDetails"
                        style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewHouseDetailsTo"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/HouseDetails"
                    style="@style/AudioFileInfoOverlayText" />

                </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_next"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="0.42"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_48dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large" />
        </LinearLayout></ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a resource reference in style.xml. Following is an example. hope this will help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style
    name="style_name"
    parent="@[package:]style/style_to_inherit">
    <item
        name="[package:]style_property_name"
        >style_value</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.. But sorry I dint get it. Do I need to add new style or package name?? So do I need to add every activity's package name?? Please can you expplain with my code..? @ovina peiris